# PHP move_uploaded_file fail to upload file

Tags: php, apache, move-uploaded-file

I have the below PHP code to upload files

```
    $uploadedFile = ''; 
    if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){ 
        // File path config 
        $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
        $targetFilePath = 'uploads/'.$fileName; 
        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
                 
        // Allow certain file formats to upload 
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 
            // Upload file to the server 
                    
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){ 
                $uploadedFile = $fileName; 
                $uploadStatus = 1;
            }else{ 
                $uploadStatus = 0; 
                $response['message'] = 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.'; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $uploadStatus = 0; 
            $response['message'] = 'Sorry, only '.implode('/', $allowTypes).' files are allowed to upload.'; 
        } 
    } 
             
    if($uploadStatus == 1){ 
                 
        // Insert form data in the database 
        $sqlInsertFilePath = "insert into soundexercises(filepath) values ('$targetFilePath')";
        $resultFilePath = pg_query($cn, $sqlInsertFilePath);

        if($resultFilePath){ 
            $response['status'] = 1; 
            $response['message'] = 'Form data submitted successfully!'; 
        } 
    } 
}else{ 
    $response['message'] = 'Please fill all the mandatory fields.';
```

I get error

```
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.
```

I check the error.log from my apache and I get the below

```
2023-01-22 16:19:25 [:error] [pid 18980:tid 140169504040704] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248:35136] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^$" against "FILES:file" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/000_i360_0.conf"] [line "158"] [id "77317957"] [msg "IM360 WAF: Track file upload||File:\\xe8\\x88\\x92\\xe6\\x9c\\x8d shufu.m4a||Size:20084||User:yskapell||SC:/var/www/vhosts/kaiqiaozhi.space/lxxxxxxx/exercises/upload_sound.php||T:APACHE||"] [severity "NOTICE"] [tag "service_i360custom"] [tag "noshow"] [hostname "xxxxxxx"] [uri "/exercises/upload_sound.php"] [unique_id "Y81F7YHZV4SyzQDeQqbhegAAAdM"], referer: https://xxxxxxx/admin/dashboard.php

2023-01-22 16:19:25 [:error] [pid 18980:tid 140169504040704] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248:35136] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^$" against "FILES_TMPNAMES:file" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/000_i360_0.conf"] [line "158"] [id "77317957"] [msg "IM360 WAF: Track file upload||File:/tmp/20230122-161925-Y81F7YHZV4SyzQDeQqbhegAAAdM-file-2buepa||Size:20084||User:yskapell||SC:/var/www/vhosts/kaiqiaozhi.space/xxxxxxx/exercises/upload_sound.php||T:APACHE||"] [severity "NOTICE"] [tag "service_i360custom"] [tag "noshow"] [hostname "xxxxxxx"] [uri "/exercises/upload_sound.php"] [unique_id "Y81F7YHZV4SyzQDeQqbhegAAAdM"], referer: https://xxxxxxx/admin/dashboard.php

2023-01-22 16:19:25 [fcgid:warn] [pid 18980:tid 140169504040704] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248:35136] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/\xe8\x88\x92\xe6\x9c\x8d shufu.m4a): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/kaiqiaozhi.space/xxxxxxx/exercises/upload_sound.php on line 63, referer: https://xxxxxxx/admin/dashboard.php

2023-01-22 16:19:25 [fcgid:warn] [pid 18980:tid 140169504040704] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248:35136] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpvatIuu' to 'uploads/\xe8\x88\x92\xe6\x9c\x8d shufu.m4a' in /var/www/vhosts/kaiqiaozhi.space/xxxxxxx/exercises/upload_sound.php on line 63, referer: https://xxxxxxx/admin/dashboard.php
2023-01-22 16:19:25 [:error] [pid 18980:tid 140169504040704] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248:35136] [client 2a02:587:e919:9900:1f9d:65ab:b74b:4248] ModSecurity: Input filter: Failed to rename file from "/tmp/20230122-161925-Y81F7YHZV4SyzQDeQqbhegAAAdM-file-2buepa" to "/var/cache/modsec-upload/20230122-161925-Y81F7YHZV4SyzQDeQqbhegAAAdM-file-2buepa". [hostname "xxxxxxx"] [uri "/exercises/upload_sound.php"] [unique_id "Y81F7YHZV4SyzQDeQqbhegAAAdM"], referer: https://xxxxxxx/dashboard.php
```

I checked the permission on the upload folder and it's 755 with correct owner.

===UPDATE===

The `$_FILES['file']['error']` return 0 .

```
1:0 {"status":0,"message":"Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.","results":"No results"}
```

Comment: Based on the ModSecurity related lines you are using a file name with UTF8 characters. May be that would be the problem...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when You provide full absolute path for the `$targetFilePath` instead of `'uploads/'.$fileName` ?

There's also **comodo** security Modsecurity warning error in Your logs.

Comment: It worked with absolute path.

Comment: I know. Error log already told everything.